# Understanding how to create multiple tab or instances with monaco

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, code-editor, react-monaco-editor

So what we are trying to do is , a user can open a tab and assign a language to me monaco editor instance

```
 <MonacoEditor
          height="600"
          language="javascript"
          theme="vs-light"
          value={code}
          options={options}
          
        />
```

and while that is active, the user can still create another monaco editor instance with python as the language

what we are currently doing is just having the code editor there like so

```
 <MonacoEditor
          height="600"
          language="javascript"
          theme="vs-light"
          value={code}
          options={options}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
        />
```

which means we can only have one instance of code editor.